# Use of Curie law in Antiferromagnetic Weiss theory derivation

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

When deriving the magnetic susceptibility of an antiferromagnetic (AFM) material Coey in the book Magnetism and Magnetic Materials (p.196) assumes that for one sublattice it holds true that $\chi = \frac{C}{T}$ since that that holds true in paramagnets (PM). However, using this he then derives that for the PM region of an AFM material the $\chi = \frac{2C}{T-\theta}$.

How can both of the equations be true??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first $\chi$ is above the Neel temperature, the second $\chi$ is below the Neel temperature of the sub-lattice where the crystal is anti-ferromagnetic. The change from one to the other is a phase change.